# rails issue with naming convention and table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an issue with rails with naming convention.

I have a database where i can't rename table so names are not in plural with **inflector**.

Today i wanted create model and controller for the table "wishlist__c" and the issue is here. I tried 3 times first by duplicating product model, controller.... and changing name then creating files myself and i still got the issue and then with **rails g scaffold wishlist__c**

**The first error when i try to go to url:8080/wishlist__c/index :**

> Routing Error
>   uninitialized constant WishlistCController

**wishlist__c_controller.rb** exist. I notice after many test that the double '__' is a problem in rails. I rename it to wishlist_c_controller and the same with the model. the error message change to

--**Solution**: I forget to rename folder wishlist__c to wishlist_c in views folder

Thanks you all ! --

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in WishlistCController#show
>   Couldn't find WishlistC with 'id'=index

the code display under this is from wishlist_c_controller.rb:

```
def set_wishlist__c
  @wishlist__c = ::WishlistC.find(params[:id])
end
```

How to solve it. I need to link my app to this table

edit:
Model **wishlist_c.rb**:

```
class WishlistC < ApplicationRecord
    self.table_name = "wishlist__c"
end
```

**wishlist_c_controller**:

```
class WishlistCController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_wishlist__c, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /wishlist__c
  # GET /wishlist__c.json
  def index
    @wishlist__c = WishlistC.all
  end

  # GET /wishlist__c/1
  # GET /wishlist__c/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /wishlist__c/new
  def new
    @wishlist__c = WishlistC.new
  end

  # GET /wishlist__c/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /wishlist__c
  # POST /wishlist__c.json
  def create
    @wishlist__c = WishlistC.new(wishlist__c_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @wishlist__c.save
        format.html { redirect_to @wishlist__c, notice: 'Wishlist  c was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @wishlist__c }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @wishlist__c.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /wishlist__c/1
  # PATCH/PUT /wishlist__c/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @wishlist__c.update(wishlist__c_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @wishlist__c, notice: 'Wishlist  c was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @wishlist__c }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @wishlist__c.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /wishlist__c/1
  # DELETE /wishlist__c/1.json
  def destroy
    @wishlist__c.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to wishlist__c_index_url, notice: 'Wishlist  c was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_wishlist__c
      @wishlist__c = WishlistC.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def wishlist__c_params
      params.fetch(:wishlist__c, {})
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you please post your models

Comment: done, i just have self.table_name otherwise he look for wishlist_c table and the table is __c

Comment: What if you go to `/wishlist__c` having renamed the controller, because of the rails conventions that should render the index, while adding `/index` will render the show, hence your error

Comment: ActionController::UnknownFormat in WishlistCController#index
WishlistCController#index is missing a template for this request format and variant. request.formats: ["text/html"] request.variant: [] NOTE! For XHR/Ajax or API requests, this action would normally respond with 204 No Content: an empty white screen. Since you're loading it in a web browser, we assume that you expected to actually render a template, not… nothing, so we're showing an error to be extra-clear. If you expect 204 No Content, carry on. That's what you'll get from an XHR or API request. Give it a shot.

Comment: Can you post the whole controller?

Comment: done. It's the classic content from rails g scaffold

Answer (score 0):

Rails create RESTful routes based on controller and model. One of the routes would be `get wishlist__c/:id` which gets mapped to action `show` of WishlistCController. so when you hit the URL `wishlist__c/index` it takes `index` as the id.

If you want to render `index` page, create a route `get wishlist__c/index` and map it to `index` method of your controller. For the above to work you must hit the URL `url:8080/wishlist__c/1` where `1` is your WishList ID. Replace it with values of `id` column of `wishlist__c` table.

Looking at your controller, you already have a route `get wishlist__c/` mapped to the `index` method of your controller. So `url:8080/wishlist__c/` should render index page for your model.

Comment: Indeed, J-dexx say something about it, he asked me to try :8080/wishlist__c i get the same error than /wishlist__c/3: 
ActionController::UnknownFormat in WishlistCController#show
WishlistCController#show is missing a template for this request format and variant.

Comment: Looks like there is some issue with your routes then.  '/wishlist__c ' is also mapped to 'show' method. Could you share the output of 'rails routes | grep wishlist' ? This will show you a list of all routes you have for wishlist model.

Comment: Also try adding the following route to your routes.rb
get 'wishlist__c' => 'wishlist__c#index'

Comment: oh sorry i copy paste the first error page without considering page name changes. on url /wishlist it's :ActionController::UnknownFormat in WishlistCController#index WishlistCController#index is missing a template for this request format and variant

Comment: Alright, so do you have an index view for WishlistCController? The error means the view you are trying to render does not exist. You must have a folder 'wishlist__c' in your views folder, and an 'index.html.erb' file generated by your scaffold command.

Comment: Solved, I renamed app/views/wishlist__c to wishlist_c. With all rename, rails was looking for index.html.erb in app/views/wishlist_c with 1 '_' too

Comment: right. that's correct. Your model, controller and views must be same.